# Invoke a controller action dynamically in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In our system, we expose API and log incoming requests.
For each request we log:

- METHOD: (e.g. put, patch, get, post)
- PATH: (e.g. `/api/users`)
- BODY: (e.g. `{ "user": { "first_name": "Alex" } }`)

I want to implement a replay feature that can repeat or "simulate" an API call given the parameters above.

What I am looking for is a method that allows me to do:

```
 simulate_request(method, path, params, headers)
```

and it simulates a real request received to my APIs, including routing and execution of the controller action + response.

Any way I can achieve this? Does Rails offer already such a method, or is there a gem that does that?
All the things I tried, didn't bring to any result so I, unfortunately, have no code to share.

Comment: What do you mean by "simulate" because I would assume this means "mock" but then you go on to state you would like it to route, execute, and respond which makes me think you want to call the actual action. If the latter understanding is true you can simply test the controller action as described [Here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers)

Comment: Building on the question above, are you looking for a way to trigger an API request using something like HTTParty gem? This would make a local request to the API from the "outside".

Comment: Check out the HTTParty gem https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

Comment: I am not trying to run a test on a controller action. I need to perform this in a production environment

Comment: httpparty might be a solution but involves going “out “ of the Rails app and invoke the real API from “outside”. This will involve also layers that should not be involved like Apache